# Permission Error while creating new file in VS code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

I get an error when i try to create a new file in VS Code while working on a project i cloned from github to work on. The error i get is this

Unable to write file '/Users/malcom/robofriends/src/Hello.js' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/malcom/robofriends/src/Hello.js')

I have changed permissions for the file to read and write. i have also enabled both Terminal and VS code to make global changes through Security and Privacy and still get the same error.

Does anyone know a working solution i can use?